# How can I pass a variable into a Date picker onSelect function

Tags: jquery, function, variables, onselect

Basically what I would like to accomplish is having a variable value inside the onSelect function. This value will be set in the Dom ready function. I need this variable to execute a function called checkDates everytime there is a change in the date picker.

```
jQuery(function(){  
  var myVar = 'xzy';
}); 

$("#PeriodStartDate").datepicker({            
  onSelect: function(dateText) {          
    console.log(myVar);
    checkDates(this.value, $('#EffectiveStartDate').val(), myVar);        
  }
});
```

Comment: Put var myVar; outside the closure and assign  myVar = 'xzy'; inside the closure?

Comment: You can't. You need to have the variable available in global scope, or call a function to retrieve it *within* the `onSelect` handler. Preferably the latter, as global variables should be avoided where possible. Also note that you appear to be defining the `datepicker()` *outside* the document.ready event handler, so it will not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myVar;
jQuery(function(){  
         myVar = 'xzy';
    }); 

$("#PeriodStartDate").datepicker({            
        onSelect: function(dateText) {          
            console.log(myVar);
            checkDates(this.value,$('#EffectiveStartDate').val(),myVar);        
        }
    });
```